# If I have this string in Python, how do I decode it?

Tags: python, encoding

s = 'Tara%2520Stiles%2520Living'

How do I turn it into:

```
Tara Stiles Living
```

Comment: Double URL-escaped space character. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
urllib.unquote(string)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Comment: this answer isn't complete! the other two answers are.

Comment: I was just providing reference to the package / method that needed to be used. Wasn't posting a "fix".

Comment: @Srirangan, then consider the downvotes and the comment a suggestion to the OP that he should unaccept this one and accept a different one that actually answers the question correctly.  (Or you could update yours, so that at least the accepted answer is a full answer.)

Comment: @Peter, sure @Alex, do as Peter says and tick mark and award up-votes to Ghostdog or Greg :P

Comment: While the other 2 answers are correct for this instance, how do you determine if when you no longer need to unquote?  What if it had been triple encoded?

Comment: @Tony Lenzi, with this type of escaping, there's no possible way to know for certain whether a string is encoded, so you can't tell when you've decoded it "completely".  You'd either have to know how many times it has been encoded, or you'd be guessing and in some (possibly not likely) cases you'd be "decoding" data that wasn't actually encoded.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use [`urllib.unquote`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote), but it appears you need to use it *twice*:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> s = 'Tara%2520Stiles%2520Living'
>>> urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(s))
'Tara Stiles Living'
```

After unquoting once, your "%2520" turns into "%20", which unquoting again turns into " " (a space).

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> s = 'Tara%2520Stiles%2520Living'
>>> t=urllib.unquote_plus(s)
>>> print t
Tara%20Stiles%20Living
>>> urllib.unquote_plus(t)
'Tara Stiles Living'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
import urllib

s = 'Tara%2520Stiles%2520Living'
t=''
while s<>t: s,t=t,urllib.unquote(s)
```

Comment: In addition to that code can you provide some context for the person who posed the question? See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python you should use urllib.parse.unquote(url) like the following code :

```
import urllib
url = "http://url-with-quoted-char:%3Cspan%3E%20%3C/span%3E"
print(url)
print(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
```

This code will output the following :

```
>>> print(url)
http://url-with-quoted-char:%3Cspan%3E%20%3C/span%3E
>>> print(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
http://url-with-quoted-char:<span> </span>
```